# How do I add custom tracing to a second-generation App Engine application in Go?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, trace, google-cloud-stackdriver

Google App Engine now supports Go 1.11 via the new [second-generation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/) standard environment.  While converting an older standard environment application to the second generation, it wasn't obvious how to combine tracing information from the app engine infrastructure with custom tracing I added to the application using [OpenCensus](https://opencensus.io/).

Even though I had created a stackdriver exporter and registered traces, I wasn't seeing custom trace information in the stackdriver console attached to inbound requests.

Answer (score 3):

The key is I was missing is understanding how span context is communicated to the serving app.  Google leverages the `X-Cloud-Trace-Context` header to propagate span context within requests sent to your serving instances, and the [go.opencensus.io/exporter/stackdriver/propagation](https://godoc.org/go.opencensus.io/exporter/stackdriver/propagation) library provides an implementation to extract and persist this information within http requests.

Don't forget to [create a stackdriver exporter](https://godoc.org/contrib.go.opencensus.io/exporter/stackdriver), and register traces to it. The docs for the exporter library show an example of this.

```
// CreateSpanFromRequest returns a context and span based on the http.Request.
// If no existing spancontext is found, this will start a new span.
// Modifies existing request to contain the generated span's context.
func CreateSpanFromRequest(name string, r *http.Request) (context.Context, *trace.Span) {
    var span *trace.Span
    ctx := r.Context()
    httpFormat := &propagation.HTTPFormat{}
    sc, ok := httpFormat.SpanContextFromRequest(r)
    if ok {
        ctx, span = trace.StartSpanWithRemoteParent(ctx, name, sc)
    } else {
        ctx, span = trace.StartSpan(ctx, name)
    }
    // Write the span context into the http.Request.  We do this to
    // to enable chaining handlers together more easily.
    httpFormat.SpanContextToRequest(span.SpanContext(), r)
    return ctx, span
}
```

Using this, I was able to add custom spans to my handlers that would be properly associated with the incoming request information in stackdriver:

```
func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    _, span := CreateSpanFromRequest("indexHandler", r)
    defer span.End()
    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello, World!")
}
```